# Fields missing in SharePoint alert email 

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I believe SharePoint alert mail includes all the fields by default from list/library until n unless there is a change in Alerttemplates.xml file. However my alert missing some fields. How do I include them ? I don't find any such place to look.

I'm not looking to modify anything in Alerttemplates.xml.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer instead of editing your question.

Comment: Sure Kyle..thanks for amendment..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The following was edited into the question, but should be an answer.  I made this a wiki to avoid getting rep from this, as its not my answer.**

---

To fix this issue we must re-register the alert template . To do so,

Here is the syntax which should be executed from command line interface ,

```
STSADM -o updatealerttemplates -url <site> -filename C:\Alerttemplates.xml -lcid 1033
```

Then

```
IISReset
```